# REST API POST returning 400 Syntax error

Tags: 8

I wrote a REST plugin for posting data to my Drupal site, When I send JSON data from browser it is returning the error `{readyState: 4, responseText: "{"error":"Syntax error"}", responseJSON: Object, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request"}` but it is working fine in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). What might be the issue?

The data I am send is  `{"name" : "user", "pass" : "userpass"}`

I am also adding the following headers in request.

```
"Content-Type", 'application/json'
"Accept", 'application/json'
```

Comment: `'content-type', 'application/hal+json'` and `Accept` is not necessary

Comment: what language does your plugin use?

Comment: @NoSssweat - I tried 'application/hal+json' now I am getting '{readyState: 4, responseText: "{}", responseJSON: Object, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type"}'. Could you please explain  what is language here?

Comment: You can use postman to [generate your code](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ylC6B.jpg)

Comment: and you can change language [over here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HOJ38.jpg)

Comment: @NoSssweat yes I added "Accept-Language: en" but still getting the same error

Comment: @NoSssweat - also I added all the header from postman but still it's not working.

Comment: I meant coding language see -> [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HOJ38.jpg)

Comment: @NoSssweat - I'm using jQuery for posting the data. When I send the data as string using JSON.stringify it is working fine but it is going to error function with 'Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "username", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}'

Comment: @NoSssweat - Thanks! it's working perfectly as expected, I used code from  postman as you suggested. Could you please tell me how I can vote for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to generate your code

[image]

Click here to change code language

[image]

Comment: Does that *postman* also ring twice? Also, any hint / suggestions about where to find something to learn more about what you can do with it? Like a video tutorial or some kind of step by step docu?